# Using Maximize with LABColor

Tags: mathematical-optimization, color

I'm writing a function that, given a color, returns a contrasting color.  It does this by maximizing the `ColorDistance` between the input and output colors.  However, I'm getting an error that's complaining about how `LABColor[l, a, b]` is symbolic and not a color, which it is until `Maximize` gives it numerical value (and ultimately does find a nominally contrasting color).  What do I do to `LABColor` to stop this error?

(Note that I don't think this scheme for finding contrasting colors is particularly good, I just want to know how to fix this error for general knowledge)

```
(* bounds of RGB space in LAB space *)
rgbCube = Cuboid[{0, -0.8, -1.13}, {1, 0.94, 0.94}];

(* Find a highly contrasting color *)
Maximize[
 ColorDistance[Pink, LABColor[l, a, b]], {l, a, b} \[Element] 
  rgbCube]
```

```
ColorDistance: Pink and LABColor[l, a, b] should be two valid color directives, images, or lists of objects with the same dimension.
```

```
Out[1]= {2.00573, {l -> 0., a -> -0.8, b -> -1.13}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid that warning by stating that they are numeric like this:

```
rgbCube = Cuboid[{0, -0.8, -1.13}, {1, 0.94, 0.94}];
f[l_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := ColorDistance[
     RGBColor[1, 0.5, 0.5], LABColor[l, a, b]]
Maximize[f[l, a, b], {l, a, b} \[Element] rgbCube]
```

[image]